# gear compatibility specification

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machine-design

I want to build a epicyclic gear system with planetary gears on flat carrier plate and outer ring as internally toothed (geared) slewing bearing. I want to buy a single row slewing bearing of 8 inch internal diameter and a compatible three spur gears of 2.5 inch outer diameter and a sun gear of 1.5 inch outer diameter. I need to communicate to online seller about my specification in technical terms. I am not a mechanical engineer and single seller do not sell both products (that is slewing bearing and spur gear mounted with ball bearing). It would be helpful if any body can tell me What specification will make sure the compatibility including backlash and root clearance. If somebody can tell me any formula I am ready to understand it.

Comment: Gear specification like outer diameter and inner diameter are not strict slewing bearing can be upto 9 inch.  I tried to get light weight slewing bearing by welding to bike chain in the internal ring of a plane ball bearing but the count of beats were problem. Also welding was ruining the ball bearing. I do not have access to laser welding etc.

Comment: Don’t weld to bearings - they are replaceable items and usually fitted into housing with a press-fit or clamped with securing nuts.